# How to delete files/directories using oc cli in Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I've used `oc cp` to copy files and directories onto a persistent volume attached to a pod in my openshift project. Is there any way to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oc exec` to execute any command inside the container, so you can use the following to execute `rm` within the container to delete files:

```
oc exec <pod-name> rm /path/to/my-file
```

or to recursively delete a folder within the container:

```
oc exec <pod-name> rm -rf /path/to/my/directory
```

Alternatively, you can use `oc rsh <pod-name>` to open an interactive terminal if the Pod contains a shell binary.

Comment: This works to delete a file from a pod but not from persistent storage.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete a persistent volume with:

`oc delete pv the-name-of-the-persistent-volume`

so for example

`oc delete pv grafana-data`

You can get the list of persistent volumes with:

`oc get pv`.